# Is it possible to cast a .NET class into a COM library class?

Tags: c#, com, windows-7, tablet-pc, microsoft-ink

I am using the `MathInputControl` class in C# through the `micautLib` COM library.

Example:

```
    MathInputControl mic = new MathInputControlClass();
    mic.EnableExtendedButtons(true);
    mic.Show();
```

---

I am using `Microsoft.Ink` and I would like to be able to send an `Ink` object to the MathInputControl object through the `MathInputControl.LoadInk(IInkDisp ink);` method. However, the IInkDisp interface is an unmanaged interface and none of the managed Microsoft.Ink classes implement it.

**How can I send it a managed Ink object?**

Comment: What is the location of the COM library `micautLib` on windows? I could not find it when I tried to add reference to it in a Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd build a `ComVisible` wrapper that implements `IInkDisp` and delegates to whatever `Microsoft.Ink` facilities you need.